# Android RecyclerView.Adapter change icon onClick

Tags: java, android, performance, android-recyclerview

I created a list item with a icon at the end. Using RecyclerView.Adapter

On icon onClick, I want to change the icon. (I can do it). But when you scroll the list up or down there will be others random list item icon changed.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(StatusViewHolder holder, int position) {
                ...

final InviteFriend data = mInviteFriend.get(position);

    if(data.isSelected()) { 

                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp); }
                holder.imageView.setTag(data);

                holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                        InviteFriend inviteFriend = (InviteFriend) imageView.getTag();
                        inviteFriend.setSelected(true);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp);
                        notifyCounterChanged(true);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recycler view the view will be recycled to save memory usage
so you need to add else in your condition

```
if(data.isSelected()) { 
    // your original code
} else {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
    //Put another code if you want
}
```

Comment: Big Thanks. I completed forgotten that RecyclerView wont save the state

Comment: You are welcome, I also forgot about it sometimes ;)

Comment: Many thanks. The problem I was having is that every list item would change to the icon that was set for the changed rows.  I was encountering this problem because I only had an `if` statement.  The else fixed it.